# string to JSONObject conversion returns null

Tags: android

This is my code :

```
JSONObject arrayobject = new JSONObject(preferences.getString("test", ""));
String responseobject = arrayobject.getString("array"+index);
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responseobject);
```

This is the arrayobject :

```
{"array0":"{"myarray":[{"innerkey":"innervalue"}],"key":"value"}"}
```

This is the responseobject (it is a string) :

```
{
  "myarray": [
    {
      "innerkey": "innervalue"
    }
  ],
  "key": "value"
}
```

Why is `object` always set to NULL ??

Please help me out!

Comment: Are you sure this is the EXACT result returned by responseobject?

Comment: this is the exact structure of the `responseobject`..

Comment: check if preference contains value with "test" key. then check if it has value with key `"array"+index`.

Comment: Are you sure your IDE doesn't add any escape character (sorry for my bad english) such as "/" or " ?

Comment: @Boss yes it does.. but object is still null

Comment: @Virthuss  I tried replacing the backslashes.. same result..

Comment: @mercy show me a screenshot of your IDE in debug mod, where you get the value of responseobject. Your JSON seems to be correct.

Comment: @Virthuss I'm sorry.. I don't wanna do that..

Comment: @mercy as responseobject returns a correct JSON, object has absolutely no reason to be NULL. Then you can copy the value from the IDE. I just need to be sure that responseobject is the one you show here.

Comment: `arrayobject` is invalid json. Try this `{"array0":{"myarray":[{"innerkey":"innervalue"}],"key":"value"}}`

Comment: arrayobject is invalid. So i doubt responseobject is the one you show us. Ensure responseobject is the one you show here.

Comment: may you post complete desired json...........

Comment: When putting those values in preference, i converted the jsonobject to a string, put it in another json object and converted the whole thing to a string, i think something went wrong there.. I put the inner jsonobject as is, and converted the whole thing to a string and the conversion worked...

Answer (score 0):

You need to take two json object for fetching json array and jsonobject from your response.

Try Below code

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(preferences.getString("test",   ""));
 JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(preferences.getString("test",   ""));
 JSONObject jbj;
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject .getString("myarray"));

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    jbj= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String innerkey= jbj.getString("innerkey");
                }

String key = jsonObject1 .getString("key");
```

Hope it helps you.